# Extends ES6 class dynamically

Tags: javascript, dynamic, ecmascript-6, extends, es6-class

how perform easily a kind of mixing or extends dynamic multiple class inheritance in js es6 ?

// example here i have 3 class but they will need to be extends from context.

```js
class Type1 { constructor() {} };
class Type2 { constructor() {} };
class Type3 { constructor() {} };
```

// and here i have other class inheritance but not need context.

```js
/** return dynamically a class*/
function dynamically_Extends(extendsType) {
    switch (extendsType) {
        case 'type1': return Type1 ;break;
        case 'type2': return Type2 ;break;
        case 'type3': return Type3 ;break;
        default: console.error('class not exist') ;break;
    };
};

class AA {
    constructor(type) {
        //not work: example of extend during constructor?
        extends dynamically_Extends(type); 
        super()
    };
};

class A extends AA{
    constructor(type) {
        super(type)
    };
};
```

what i want it have something like this when i create objects

```js
const obj1 = new A('type1'); // class heritance: A=>AA=>type1
const obj2 = new A('type2'); // class heritance: A=>AA=>type2
const obj3 = new A('type3'); // class heritance: A=>AA=>type3
```

i want extends `A` 2nd time but with a dynamic context according to conditions.
Any tips or easy way to perform this during constructor or after ?
I want keep class sugar code for all thing.

Comment: i think you would have to move the class into dynamically_Extends to avoid a syntax error. the constructor could be defined as a function inside of dynamically_Extends, but outside of the class, so that all three classes can use the same code.

Comment: Whats your usecase? What keeps you from ``type === "type1" ? new A() : new B()` ?

Comment: A will be `[containerSpriteSheets,containerSpineSheets,containerAnimationSheets]`
extends `baseContainer` and extend dynamically if need context `[dataTypeDoor,dataTypeCase,dataTypeChara,dataTypeTree,dataTypeLight....]`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to all the other benefits classes provide, they also promise a certain API. Dynamic extension would make it relatively much easier to break such promises. (though it's pretty easy to do so without dynamic extensions anyways in JS). E.g. does `obj1` support `Type1.prototype.method1`?  `Type2.prototype.method2`?

An alternative and more traditional (thereby easier to maintain and read) approach to consider, could be to reorganize you class hierarchy. Class `Type1`, `Type2`, and `Type3` could inherit from `class A`.

Comment: the issue is i have also many other hirachie
`class A extends AA`, `class B extends AA`, `class C extends AA`
In my context i have something like this:
Those class : `[containerSpriteSheets,containerSpineSheets,containerAnimationSheets]`
herite this class `baseContainer`
And only if need also herite one of those class `[dataTypeDoor,dataTypeCase,dataTypeChara,dataTypeTree,dataTypeLight....]`